# How do I create a SHA256 Hash with Salt?

Tags: c#, hash, comparison

I am currently working on a visual studio C# windows form project. However, I am confused by how SHA256 + salted works. I found some examples online but unable to understand how can I call this function.

I would like to call this function in a login form connecting to a database (Microsoft Access 2010).

- How do I call this function by a click of a button and reading the
  password from a `Textbox`?
- How do i display out the hash value in a
  `Messagebox.Show` method? (For my testing purpose)
- Is it possible to
  compare two text (hashed and salted) and giving a positive result?

  ```
  public static string sha256encrypt(string phrase, string UserName)
  {
      string salt = CreateSalt(UserName);
      string saltAndPwd = String.Concat(phrase, salt);
      UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
      SHA256Managed sha256hasher = new SHA256Managed();
      byte[] hashedDataBytes =      sha256hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(saltAndPwd));
      string hashedPwd = String.Concat(byteArrayToString(hashedDataBytes), salt);
      return hashedPwd;
  }

  public static string byteArrayToString(byte[] inputArray)
  {
      StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
      for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
      {
          output.Append(inputArray[i].ToString("X2"));
      }
      return output.ToString();
  }

  private static string CreateSalt(string UserName)
  {
      string username = UserName;
      byte[] userBytes; 
      string salt;
      userBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username);
      long XORED = 0x00; 

      foreach (int x in userBytes)
          XORED = XORED ^ x;

      Random rand = new Random(Convert.ToInt32(XORED));
      salt = rand.Next().ToString();
      salt += rand.Next().ToString();
      salt += rand.Next().ToString();
      salt += rand.Next().ToString();
      return salt;
  }
  ```

How do I create an SHA256 hash with salt?

```
shavalue = (sha256encrypt("password", "username");
saltedandhashtext = CreateSalt(shavalue);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd trust this piece of code without reading *and understanding* it, as it calls SHA-256 "encryption" and only uses up to 256 different salt values...

Comment: I wouldn't waste any time on getting this code to work. Throw it out, and start with new code. In particular use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` which uses a stretched hashfunction and can create a salt by itself.

Comment: Since you are hashing passwords, you should consider to use a slow key-derivation function like PBKDF2, in CSharp it can be implemented with the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.100%29) class, as CodesInChaos already mentioned.

Comment: @CodesInChaos ... Please take note for .Net 7 :  SYSLIB0041: Some Rfc2898DeriveBytes constructors are obsolete.  Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0041   I found this out just TODAY 11Apr2023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question look at CC Inc's answer.

To the second point:
`MessageBox.Show(sha256encrypt(textBox1.Text, "SampleUserName"));`

3) Yes, it is.

You can compare two strings with the `==` comparator or `string.Equals()`.

```
public bool compareHashs(string hash1, string hash2){
   if(hash1.Equals(hash2) //or hash1 == hash2
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you would do is, on the click of the button, pass the textbox value and username to the `sha256encrypt` function, for example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sha256encrypt(textBox1.Text, "SampleUserName");
    }
```

For the second question, do the same but with Messagebox.Show:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sha256encrypt(textBox1.Text, "SampleUserName"));
    }
```

Third point: I am not sure exactly what you mean, but if you want to Salt a text and compare it with the Hashed text:

```
if(sha256encrypt("password", "username") == CreateSalt("password"))
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

Or if you want to compare them manually:

```
MessageBox.Show(sha256encrypt("password", "username") + "\n\r" + CreateSalt("password"));
```

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Did you mean to post on the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ComputeSHA256Hash(string rawData)
{
    // Create a SHA256   
    using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
    {
        // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
        byte[] bytes = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));
        // Convert byte array to a string   
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct way to do it now.  Sha256Managed has been deprecated, SHA256.Create() is now the method they are saying to use.